# How to access web page on a server using the IP 10.0.0.3?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, centos6, httpd

I have three internal servers that will never have any connection to the internet.  I've had to build a local yum repo to set them up with tools like bugzilla and the like.  However, all three are connected together and I connect to them through an ethernet connection that hooks straight into my laptop.

On one of the servers, I would like to run web sites for others to see internally when they also hook into the ethernet connection. I've installed httpd and started it, but going to the a webpage on my laptop and trying to summon 10.0.0.3 does not bring up anything.

I'm assuming that my laptop thinks I'm looking at it's web server and has no idea how to access the other server.  This is a Cent OS server I want to use for internal web pages, btw.  How can I get DNS set up on this air gapped server, only accessible by ethernet so I can server web sites on it?

I've specified the vhost as 10.0.0.3:80 and also have the Listen on 10.0.0.3:80, but I know I'm missing something else that's crucial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you verified if the IPtables are not blocking the port 80 from streamin outside localhost?

```
iptables -L
```

try this and see if you have the port available to the LAN

UPDATE
as Jake mentioned, you can open the port by

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

this should be more then enough.

Comment: That was it!  I always forget about the iptables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

also, if you are interested in exploiting the DNS option.
I used this link to answer the concern

http://www.broexperts.com/part-3-bind-server-installation-configurations/

Comment: Thanks.  I can't try any of the suggestions until I'm back at work tomorrow, but this ^ looks helpful....

Answer (score 1):

From the client machines, run NMAP to see if port 80 is open:

```
nmap 10.0.0.3 -p80
```

If it is not open, the response will be something like this. Meaning something is blocking port 80:

```
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http
```

What you want to see is:

```
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp open http
```